# How can I display images similar to Tumblr's photosets?

Tags: html, css, image, wordpress

I'm converting my wife's blog over to Wordpress and I want to display image galleries similar to how they're displayed on Tumblr. Here's an example of the layout:
http://bobbyandmaura.com/post/8195960363/photoset_iframe/bobbyandmaura/tumblr_lp2nebJFEW1qhd8ae/500

I can handle the markup and CSS for displaying the images. What I need help with is understanding how I can create this dynamically. Tumblr is smart enough to dynamically display different quantities of images while still always filling all of the space. Here's another example with fewer image:
http://bobbyandmaura.com/post/6700400507/photoset_iframe/bobbyandmaura/tumblr_ln23gi8EqU1qhd8ae/500

Hopefully I can use math to create a dynamic solution so I don't have to manually create a bunch of different possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

OK. Solved. I got a hack to show WP gallery as Tumblr photoset. It is not as customizable as Tumblr, this will only show the first image as the cover image(larger) and rest images in small grid like set.

---

You need to edit wp-includes/media.php file. If your theme as any other gallery file, you have to edit that. Edit at your own risk as this is core file of WP. If you update your WP in future, you have to do this again. Sorry, I have no time to write a plugin.

---

Search for "foreach ( $attachments as $id => $attachment )" in wp-includes/media.php and change the following (replace the foreach loop)

```
$ccg = 1;   
foreach ( $attachments as $id => $attachment ) {
        if($ccg == 1)
        {
            $link = isset($attr['link']) && 'file' == $attr['link'] ? wp_get_attachment_link($id, large, false, false) : wp_get_attachment_link($id, $size, true, false);
        }
        else
        {
            $link = isset($attr['link']) && 'file' == $attr['link'] ? wp_get_attachment_link($id, $size, false, false) : wp_get_attachment_link($id, $size, true, false);
        }
        $output .= "<{$itemtag} class='gallery-item'>";
        $output .= "
            <{$icontag} class='gallery-icon'>
                $link
            </{$icontag}>";
        if ( $captiontag && trim($attachment->post_excerpt) ) {
            $output .= "
                <{$captiontag} class='wp-caption-text gallery-caption'>
                " . wptexturize($attachment->post_excerpt) . "
                </{$captiontag}>";
        }
        $output .= "</{$itemtag}>";
        if ( ( $columns > 1 && ++$i % $columns == 1) || $ccg == 1 )
            $output .= '<br style="clear: both" />';
        $ccg++;

    }
```

Demo gallery can be found at http://ontrip.in/the-ca-cur-badi-forest-resort-gorumara/

---

You may need to modify your Gallery columns number. You may select the cover image by alternating the image order in Gallery insert box.

Answer (score 0):

My friend [Victor Gonzáles](https://twitter.com/#!/aficiomaquinas) developed Aurum to manage proportions and have that nice effect. You can get it here: https://github.com/aficiomaquinas/Aurum-CSS

You then additionally group the images by similar proportions(w/h) with a tolerance of 0.2. So that <0.2 is one group < 0.4 another, < 0.6, etc.
Then have a random chance of spawning them in 1,2,3 columns / row.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm more looking for some way to say "Hey I have these X number of pictures with Y in landscape and Z in portrait. Here is how they can be tiled together programmatically".

All of the images in the tumblr example are getting inline sizing styles that have been calculated somehow from the server.

Comment: Well, I have no idea of what you want. Have you tried grouping by similar proportions and giving a random chance of having 1,2,3 photos per row?